# Read lines from a text file and sort into separate variables

Tags: c#

**config.txt** *(content)*

```
databaseHost = localhost;
databaseUsername = root;
databasePassword = root;
databaseName = test;
```

C# Code

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("config.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        list.Add(line); // Add to list.

        Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

This currently prints out everything in the text file. 
I want to store the text into public variables (which I have already declared). I have tried using String.Split. I think I used it wrong, however if anybody here can lead me in the right direction, I will be very grateful. I am still learning and I am very young!

---

I made some progress:
Heres my new C# file

```
 char[] equals = { '=' };
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("config.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                list.Add(line); // Add to list.
                string[] linr = line.Split(equals);





                Console.WriteLine(linr[1]); // Write to console.
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

And it outputs

```
 localhost;
 root;
 root;
 test;
```

It's going well.

Comment: It would help if you posted the content of your text file. Also if this is a standard CSV file format there are existing tools (search NuGet.org) that can do the parsing for you.

Comment: `"I have tried using String.Split."` - Not according to the code in the question you didn't.  What did you actually try and in what way did it not produce the desired result?

Comment: I didn't know how to do it properly. Sorry.

Comment: I did post the content on my txt file

Comment: @ShawnCoker - right you are, it was not apparent to me that was the content. Ill edit your post...

Comment: Right, so it sounds like you've solved the "read lines from a text file" part. Now you can hard-code the data and ignore the file part of the problem, concentrating on the processing of the data. Your [mcve] should contain that hard-coded data, and no file access.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. Again, there are plenty of tools out there that you can reuse on NuGet.org. This is based on the format you have listed above with name/values split by `=` sign. It does not drop the trailing `;` but I am not sure if that is in your text file intentionally or for some other reason. The easiest thing to do is not include it at all.

```
// top of code file
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
// top of code file


public Config config { get; set; }

public void ParseMethod() {
    var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("config.txt")
        .Select(x => x.Split(new[] {'='}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
        .Select(x => new {Name = x[0].Trim(), Value = x[1].Trim()})
        .ToList();

    config = new Config(){
        DatabaseHost = text.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "DatabaseHost")?.Value,
        DatabaseUsername = text.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "DatabaseUsername")?.Value,
        DatabasePassword = text.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "DatabasePassword")?.Value,
        DatabaseName = text.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "DatabaseName")?.Value,
    };
}
```

**Config.cs**

```
public class Config
{
    public string DatabaseHost { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseUsername { get; set; }
    public string DatabasePassword { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [System.IO.File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
var list = File.ReadAllLines("config.txt");
```

In order to store the members in separate variables you can use reflection or simply map each variable hard coded. Here's the reflection way.:

```
public class MyVars
{
    public string databaseHost;
    public string databaseUsername;
    public string databasePassword;
    public string databaseName;
}

var instance = new MyVars();
var type = typeof(MyVars);
File.ReadAllLines("config.txt").
     Select(l => l.Split(new char[]{'=',';'})).
     ForEach(a => type.GetField(a[0].Trim()).
     SetValue(instance, a[1].Trim()));
```

Comment: Not sure how that helps the OP get those public fields they mention in the question. As of now the question cannot be answered as the there is no mention on the format of the file.

Comment: ^ This, in no way does this answer the OP. He's already reading them in.

Comment: @Igor ,Dispersia - Didn't notice the second part of his question, I've edited and answered.